# uuid = UUID(uuidString: String) create uppercase Letters

Tags: ios, uuid, vapor

I have a problem with the function UUID(uuidString: String). Passing a UUID as String with lower case letters the above function generates a UUID with upper case letters. Can anyone give me a hint as to what is causing this.

Use case:
Server :Database server with Vapor 4 and Postgres DB. Storage should be user specific
Client: iOS with login procedure, server responds with UserID and token, both stored in UserDefaults.standard with key.
URL's are dynamically generated with the UserID and sent as HTTP request to the server.
Server checks UserID passed this way and doesn't recognize it, because Postgres DB creates and stores UUID's with lower case letters. However, the URL generated in the client contains the corresponding UUID of the logged-in user with upper case letters.

Comment: UUID().uuidString.lowercased()
Why don't you try the comparison after you've converted uppercase to lowercase?

Comment: In the UserDefault the UUID is stored with lower case letters. If I now have to create a UUID from the string, I can do this using the above function. How should I correct now.

Comment: select upper(id::TEXT) from uuid; try this

Answer (score 2):

Technically, `uuid = UUID(uuidString: String)` creates a UUID object with an internal representation of 16 `UInt8` bytes which is case independent:

[image]

```swift
let uuid1 = UUID(uuidString: "9E9BF10C-06E2-4200-AE1A-B15F7960EEAF")!
print(uuid1.uuid)
// (158, 155, 241, 12, 6, 226, 66, 0, 174, 26, 177, 95, 121, 96, 238, 175)
let uuid2 = UUID(uuidString: "9e9bf10c-06e2-4200-ae1a-b15f7960eeaf")!
print(uuid2.uuid)
// (158, 155, 241, 12, 6, 226, 66, 0, 174, 26, 177, 95, 121, 96, 238, 175)
```

A complicating factor is that Swift implements `.uuidString` to return an uppercased representation. (Inherited from Apple's `NSUUID` which has lots of legacy use.) Whereas, many other projects follow the [RFC 4122 Section 3 "Namespace Registration Template"](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122#section-3) guidance:

> The internal representation of a UUID is a specific
> sequence of bits in memory …
>
> The *hexadecimal values "a" through "f" are
> output as lower case characters*
> and are case insensitive on input.

In my use case, I've extended the Swift `UUID` with `.rfc4122String` to provide a lowercased uuid string in a way that expresses standard compliance intent.

```swift
public extension UUID {
    /// lowercased string per RFC 4122 section 3 guidelines
    var rfc4122String: String {
        return self.uuidString.lowercased()
    }
}
```

Also, if ambiguously-cased UUID strings are present, the conversion to a `UUID` object will both (1) validate the uuid string by the `init()` not returning `nil` and (2) allow for UUID-to-UUID case-independent comparison.

Comment: First of all thank you for your effort